# Is the B major chord in the given progression(in key of A major) a secondary dominant?

Tags: jazz

[image]
This is a popular Indian film song composed by Amit Trivedi in key of A major

I was analysing this and need help verifying the same.

In the 8th bar there is B Major chord resolving the C#min7 in previous bar to DMaj7 in next bar. I am not sure what can we call this B chord. Is it a secondary dominant? But that would be ambiguous as they are used to resolve 2-5-1s as V/V and so on(as per my limited understanding)

P.S below is the link to the song

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: I have edited this answer based on things I heard in the recording after listening over a better audio system.

In this case that chord is a V/V but not because if goes to a Dmaj7 chord but because that chord is actually a Dmaj7/E, making it an E13sus4. Another aside is the B chord has a 3rd (D#) in the bass.

In the second section, which is the same material with variations, that part of the progression does resolve to a Dmaj7 in what would be bar 17. In this case you can think of the B chord as simply a II chord (with the 3rd in the bass). It’s a common non-diatonic chord which can be said to come from the Lydian mode. You can find a II chord in “Eight Days a Week” by the Beatles, among many others. There are many other songs that use a II chord in this or other ways, like “Sitting on the Dock Of The Bay” A-C#-D-B, or I-III-IV-II, then back to I.

Some songs use a II7 such as “Take the A Train, “Girl from Ipanema” and “Watch what Happens” (all these songs have very similar chord progressions in their A sections) but in this case it can also be seen as a V/V since it does go to a V with a ii chord in between the II and V. In C: C-D7-Dm7-G7-C.

Comment: I posed a question about sec. doms., and the answers came that V/V can still be a sec. dom. even if it doesn't go straight to V. Haven't worked out the logic behind that yet, though.

Comment: @Tim I would be curious to see your question, can you post a link here in comments? I do not have a traditional classical approach to harmony so the way I see it is if you’re going to call something a secondary dominant it has to resolve to the dominant at some point within the natural flow of the phrase. That’s why the first B chord is V/V and the second is not. The first Dmaj7 is actually over an E bass which makes it a V13sus4. Even if there were a buffer chord in between it would still have a secondary dominant flavor. The second B does not have the E in the bass so that makes it a II.

Answer (score -1):

Any chord that is out of key may be considered as a secondary dominant. In key A, chord B will be V/V - as the dominant of the dominant E. It doesn't even have to be followed by the expected E (V), to be called a sec.dom.

To be more specific - a secondary dominant is the dominant of a chord belonging to the key. So, in key A (OP's question), the sec.doms would be one of F♯ (>B/Bm), G♯ (>C&sharp/m), A (>D), B (>E), C♯ (>F♯m). E wouldn't be a sec.dom., as it's the dominant of A.

Comment: Being a secondary dominant means that is a dominant chord in a specific key. A "secondary chord" can be, effectively, any chord, but "dominant" is specific.

Answer (score -1):

I listened to the first page's worth of music and more of that original YouTube video. **Several notes in the transcription you provided are wrong.**

**In the original, unlike the transcription, the D below Middle C in Bars 2, 4, and 9 simply isn't there.** To add insult to injury, Beat 2.5 of Bar 11 has a B below Middle C in the original that isn't there in the transcription.

**Bars 2, 4, and 9 therefore should have F♯m chords instead of Dmaj7 chords.**  Thus, **the entire first page is in F sharp minor instead of A major**. It is not until later in the song that the key unambiguously shifts to A major (the song notably ends in A major).

Thus, **the problem chord in Bar 8 is a IV chord (in F sharp minor)**, not a chord that needs an explanation in A major. Note that this chord resolves into a tonic, F♯m chord in Bar 9.

Comment: The transcription may not be totally accurate but the basic analysis and flavor of the harmony is. The first 4 bars (not including the anacrusis) sound like IV-I-IV-iii in A. The second A section at bar 10 confirms the D root in bar 2 even though the rest of the harmony uses different inversions.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - I listened to that beginning and, again, **the entire first page sounds like it is in F sharp minor instead**. There are no D's in the original's piano in Bars 2, 4, and 9, F sharp sounds like the tonic as a result, and Bars 2-5 sound like i - VII - i - III9 in F sharp minor. Bar 10 sounds like VI in F sharp minor. It isn't until we *leave the first page* that the song starts sounding like it shifted to A major.

Comment: There is a D in the bass, especially clear at bar 10 with the R-5 on beat 1. In bars 2 and 4 it sounds like a root position Dmaj7 which does contain an F# minor triad. The second chord, the A sounds like the home chord, a IV-I progression. The melody resolves around A and E as well which are 1 and 5 but would be the 3rd and 7th in F# minor.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - Very weird. I listened to that video on 2 different sound systems. The only D I could detect in Bar 2 in any of them is a D way below the C below Middle C, audible only at 50% speed with my smartphone.

Comment: It is very soft and  might even be played an octave lower than where it is written. There are issues with the transcription. To me the confirmation is the D in bar 10.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - Bar 10 sounds like a substitute for the F sharp minor tonic - *a distinctly different chord from the tonic-sounding chord in Bar 9*. It sounds like a *purposeful departure* from the previous measures and not a semi-rip-off of Bar 2.

Comment: I'm with @JohnBelzaguy on this one. mm. 2, 4, 7, 9, and 10 all contain DMaj7 chords.

Comment: I think the melody hints the `Amaj`: c# e c# b **a**, a b c# **e**, it's a play with the relative minors of `Amaj` and `Emaj`. If you play that melody with `Amaj` and `Emaj` instead of `F#min7` and `C#min7` the tonal pivot is clear. If the melody was for example c# e c# b **f#**, a b c# **e** then it would hint `F#min` in my perception.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity - Harmonies override melodies *very* strongly when it comes to determining the key. Take, for example, how ["In the Whirlpool"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CR_SWRqGX94) from *Dance Dance Revolution: Mario Mix* is in B minor while it takes its melodies from Pomp and Circumstance March No. 1 in D Major - yes, it reharmonizes D major and G major melodies into *B minor*!

Comment: I did try messing around with the Musescore piano, and I found that, given the first chord and melody note of Bar 2, if I set the lowest note's velocity to 10 below all the others, *I basically couldn't hear it at all*. The old conundrum - if a note is so much quieter than the others, should it be transcribed, and should it be a first-class note in the harmonic analysis? Note that the B below Middle C in Beat 2.5 of Bar 11 of the original is a *lot* louder and more detectable.

Comment: @Dekkadeci *"Harmonies override melodies very strongly when it comes to determining the key"*. Oh I agree, that's why I used the word *hints*, and mentioned the (initial) melody as a piece of context that in this specific song I perceive as useful information for ambiguous key detection.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity - Sorry, I was trying to hint that the melody is basically not useful at all when the harmony overrides it without clashing. Polytonality occurs when the harmony clashes with the melody to the point of being unable to override it completely, but the melody hints at a completely different key from the harmony. The harmony here overrides instead of clashes, so....